# Error: IO error: lock /home/admin/chain/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machines, cloud

After logging into my Azure linux vm through ssh. I cd 
Error: IO error: lock /home/admin_dennis/.hsd/chain/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable